# Returning a specific type from a method based on input parameter type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have 4 input type classes say

- T1: class AInput, class BInput, class CInput and class DInput

I also have 3 output type classes say

- T2: XOutput, class YOutput and class ErrorOutput

now I have to write a generic method say **"GetResponse"** in service class as per follows-

1. if input parameter of the method `GetResponse` belongs to class *AInput* and class *BInput*, then this method should return class **XOutput**.
2. if input parameter of the method `GetResponse` belongs to class *CInput* and class *DInput*, then this method should return class **YOutput**.
3. in case of any error, this method will return type class **ErrorOutput**.

Now my question is whether it is possible for a service class having a generic method to follow above conditions?

Comment: Can you show some source code? Are the classes related as in inheritance? Are we talking a WCF service or in-process?

Comment: Basically these classes are DTO (data transfer objects having fields only) and categorized into two groups-
Request: AInput, BInput, CInput and DInput

Answer (score 0):

No, generic type constraints are not capable of such advanced concepts in .NET. You could provide overloads instead:

```
XOutput Foo (AInput a);
XOutput Foo (BInput b);
YOutput Foo (CInput b);
YOutput Foo (DInput b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do some form of this by implementing an `interface` for all the input and output classes you have. Like others have mentioned this could also be done with a base class, but imo using an interface is better and since you cant inherit multiple classes but implement multiple interfaces.

input classes and interfaces:

```
interface IInput {}

class AInput : IInput {}

class BInput : IInput {}

class CInput : IInput {}
```

output classes and interfaces:

```
interface IOutput {}

class XOutput : IOutput {}

class YOutput : IOutput {}

class ErrorOutput : IOutput {}
```

Method:

```
public IOutput GetResponse(IInput input)
{
    if (input is AInput || input is BInput)
    {
        return new XOutput();
    }

    if (input is CInput || input is DInput)
    {
        return new YOutput();
    }

    return new ErrorOutput();
}
```

Usage:

```
var input = new AInput();

var response = GetResponse(input);

if(response is XOutput)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input was {0} and output was {1}", input.GetType().Name, response.GetType().Name);
} else if (response is YOutput)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input was {0} and output was {1}", input.GetType().Name, response.GetType().Name);
}
```

Output:

```
"Input was Ainput and output was XOutput"
```

Comment: Thanks furier. I've this design. but client want like this-
AInput a = new AInput()//for BInput also
//and populate all of fields, then he simply want to call like-
a.DoRequest() and return type should be of XOutput.
for CInput c = new CInput(); c.DoProcess() return type should be YOutput. any clue?

Comment: then you should just use overloads of the same function like D.R suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking WCF services here, you can not have so-called "open" generics. Microsoft differentiates between open and closed generics in the following way:

- Open generics are methods like `GetStuff<T>`, where T can be specified by the caller, and therefore is left open.
- Closed generics are methods like `GetStuff<int>`. The type is known right away, and WCF can determine what type will be passed for its WSDL.

The formet isn't supported, the latter is. This means you'll have to go through some trouble to make pseudo-generics work on your WCF services.

One way of doing it is declaring a base class for every type you'll return through your action, like for example `OutputBase` in your case. You can then create your other output types on top of that by inheriting the base class, and put something along the lines of this in your web service:

```
public OutputBase GetResponse(Type type, params object[] args)
{
    if (typeof(type) == typeof(AInput) || typeof(type) == typeof(BInput))
    {
        // Return object of type XOutput which inherits OutputBase here.
        var ret = new XOutput();
        return ret;
    }

    if (typeof(type) == typeof(CInput) || typeof(type) == typeof(DInput))
    {
        // Return stuff of type YOutput here.
        var ret = new YOutput();
        return ret;
    }

    return new ErrorOutput();
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if you can actually pass `Type` in a WCF service call either, but assuming you can't you could pass the `Type.FullName` as a string and reconstruct it later using `Type.GetType(string)` to cast it to the one you're after.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use Generics, then the GetResponse methods can be defined like

```
public XOutput GetResonse<TInput1, TInput2>(TInput1 input1, TInput2 input2, out ErrorOutput error)
    where TInput1 : AInput 
    where TInput2 : BInput
{

}

public YOutput GetResonse<TInput1, TInput2>(TInput1 input1, TInput2 input2, out ErrorOutput error)
    where TInput1 : CInput 
    where TInput2 : DInput
{

}
```

Comment: You won't be able to use open generics like that in WCF services; it can't determine it's WSDL from it.